# parse Json and create html with similar content

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have a json file and need to generate html of it.

```
<code>{
    "Exhibitors": {
        "Exhibitor": [
            {
                "LOGO": "logo1.jpg",
                "TYPE": "Exhibitor"
            },
            {
                "LOGO": "logo2.jpg",
                "TYPE": "Exhibitor"
            },
            {
                "LOGO": "logo3.jpg",
                "TYPE": "silver"
            },
            {
                "LOGO": "logo4.jpg",
                "TYPE": "gold"
            }
        ]
    }
}</code>
```

I need to create 1 list (li) for all the TYPE. and again loop through the json to generate separate divs containing Data of same TYPE.

I am able to generate list using the below code:

```
<code>
jquery.ajax({
url: "js/sponsors.json",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
        var json = jquery.parseJSON(data);
        var getTYPE = {};
        var items = json.Exhibitors.Exhibitor;
        var types = [];
        var j = 1;
        for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
           var type = item.TYPE;
           if (!(type in getTYPE)) {
              getTYPE[type] = 1;
              if (type != "" && type != "Test") {
                  types.push(type);
                  jquery('ul').append('<li id=tab"' + j + '"><a>' + type + '</a> </li>');
                  j++; 
              }
            }
        }
        }
})
</code>
```

But when looping through the data to segregate the content of similar types, the above code doesn't work. Please suggest a break through.

The HTML Should look like this:

```
<code>
< ul>
< li>Exhibiotor< /li>
< li>Silver< /li>
< li>Gold< /li>
< /ul>

< div>Exhibitor
  < div>logo1.jpg< /div>
  < div>logo2.jpg< /div>
< /div>

< div>Silver
  < div> logo3.jpg< /div>
< /div>

< div>Gold
  < div> logo4.jpg< /div>
< /div>
</code>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some closeing braces in the code.

Comment: Btw: Why your dataType is "text" and not "json"?

Comment: Could you show what the resulting HTML should be? I'm not understanding the description.

Comment: updated the question with the HTML requirement. thanks

Comment: What's with all the `<code>` tags? To mark code in SO, indent it with 4 spaces using the `{ }` tool in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just putting `1` in `getTYPE`, make each element an array of all the logos.

```
    for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
       var type = item.TYPE;
       if (!(type in getTYPE)) {
          getTYPE[type] = [item.LOGO];
          if (type != "" && type != "Test") {
              types.push(type);
              jquery('ul').append('<li id=tab"' + j + '"><a>' + type + '</a> </li>');
              j++; 
          }
        } else {
          getTYPE[type].push(item.LOGO);
        }
    }
```

Then you can loop through `getTYPE` to make all the DIVs with the logos.

```
$.each(getTYPE, function(type, logos) {
    $.each(logos, function(i, logo) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I am trying the below code to append dynamic HTML snippet but it doesn't add the logos at expected html 


    $.each(lookup, function(type, logos) {                    
    $('.tabContent').append('<div id="sponsorsTab' + j + '"><h2> '+type+'      </h2><div class="container"></div></div>')
                
    if(type="Exhibitor"){
    var exhTemp = '<div class="sponsor pd-t40 exhibitors"><ul>'
    $.each(logos, function(i, logo) {
    exhTemp=+ '<li>'+logo+'</li>'
    });
    exhTemp =+ '</ul></div>'
    }
    $('sponsorsTab' + j )..find('.container').append(exhTemp);
    });

Comment: How many times are you going to keep trying that before you realize that you can't put formatted code in comments? Edit the question.

Comment: Apologies. I have not used the Stackover flow Help too much thus not aware of the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = json.Exhibitors.Exhibitor;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i]['TYPE'] != "Test") {
        if ($('#' + items[i]['TYPE']).length == 0) {
            $('<div/>', {
                id: items[i]['TYPE'],
                text: items[i]['TYPE']
            }).appendTo('body');
        };
        $('ul').append('<li>' + items[i]['TYPE'] + '</li>');
        $('#' + items[i]['TYPE']).append('<div>' + items[i]['LOGO'] + '</div>');
    }
}
```

Result:

```
<div id="Exhibitor">Exhibitor
    <div>logo1.jpg</div>
    <div>logo2.jpg</div>
</div>
<div id="silver">silver
    <div>logo3.jpg</div>
</div>
<div id="gold">gold
    <div>logo4.jpg</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/89Lfw491/)